# Minimize $f(m)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^m / m^n $

Tags: optimization, summation

For what real value of $m$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^m}{m^n} $ is minimized?

I've been told that it's equivalent of solving for $ \text{Li}_{-n}\left(\frac1n\right)$ for the [polylogarithmic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Is there a way to solve this other than by plug and chug?

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you AlexR, I didn't know of such a policy.